# How to restart a scene in cocos2d using UIViewController

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have to restart a scene created in cocos2d using a defined UIViewController. How can i do this? Please let me know how i can do  this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try to call something like

```
- (void) restart
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[[self class] node]];
}
```

i think, it will work, but it is not good. IMHO, much better is to use smth like this

```
- (void) restart
{
    // remove all your content
    [self removeAllChildrenWithCleanup];

    // reinitialize your instances

    // re-add content again
    [self addContent];
}
```